# Ошибка запуска файлов при использовании Enigma Protector

Tags: c#, .net, обфускация

При использовании [Enigma Protector](https://enigmaprotector.com/ru/home.html) не удаётся запустить файлы с помощью `Process.Start(path)`. В исключении выводится следующее сообщение:

[image: Ошибка. Операция была отменена пользователем]

Основная программа запускается с такими правами:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Нужно что-то изменить в настройках *Enigma* или запускать файлы другим методом (возможно с параметрами)?

Comment: версия дотнета какая?

Comment: @aepot `v4.0.30319`

Comment: Файлы защищены или программа защищена? Дотнет староват, точнее очень древний.

Comment: платформа 4.7.2, версия 4.0.30319. Защищена программа, файлы разные пробовала, одинаковый исход.